# f-string representation different than str()

Tags: python, enums, f-string

I had always thought that f-strings invoked the `__str__` method.  That is, `f'{x}'` was always the same as `str(x)`.  However, with this class

```py
class Thing(enum.IntEnum):
    A = 0
```

`f'{Thing.A}'` is `'0'` while `str(Thing.A)` is `'Thing.A'`.  This example doesn't work if I use `enum.Enum` as the base class.

What functionality do f-strings invoke?

Comment: In Python3.11 the `str()` output has been changed to match the `.format()` method for `IntEnum`, `IntFlag`, and the new `StrEnum` -- so in the case above both `f'{Thing.A}'` and `str(Thing.A)` would result in `0`.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

From ["Formatted string literals" in the Python reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):
f-strings invoke the "[`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) protocol", meaning that the [`__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) magic method is called instead of `__str__`.

```py
class Foo:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo()"

    def __str__(self):
        return "A wild Foo"
    
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        if not format_spec:
            return "A formatted Foo"
        return f"A formatted Foo, but also {format_spec}!"

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> repr(foo)
'Foo()'
>>> str(foo)
'A wild Foo'
>>> format(foo)
'A formatted Foo'
>>> f"{foo}"
'A formatted Foo'
>>> format(foo, "Bar")
'A formatted Foo, but also Bar!'
>>> f"{foo:Bar}"
'A formatted Foo, but also Bar!'
```

If you don't want `__format__` to be called, you can specify `!s` (for `str`), `!r` (for `repr`) or `!a` (for [`ascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii)) after the expression:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> f"{foo}"
'A formatted Foo'
>>> f"{foo!s}"
'A wild Foo'
>>> f"{foo!r}"
'Foo()'
```

This is occasionally useful with strings:

```py
>>> key = 'something\n nasty!'
>>> error_message = f"Key not found: {key!r}"
>>> error_message
"Key not found: 'something\\n nasty!'"
```

Answer (score 39):

f-strings in Python don't use `__str__` or `__repr__`. They use `__format__`.
So to get the same result as `f'{Thing.A}'`, you'd need to call `format(Thing.A)`.

The `__format__(...)` method allows you to add more formatting features (for example with floats you can do `{:.2f}` to round the number to two decimals).

If `format()` hasn't been defined for a class/object, python will fall back to `__str__`. That's why most people think `str()` is the method used in f-strings.

The docs cover the options you have with `__format__` in detail: [Link to Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__)